# Unexpected behaviour of SELECT when value being looked for is number followed by letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table:

```
Entity
   ID : int
   Name : varchar(10)
```

I was looking up entities by their ID and found a result that surprised me. Let's assume that an entity with ID = 10 exists. When I run the following queries, I get the following results:

```
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = 10        Found Entity 10 (as expected)
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = '10'      Found Entity 10 (as expected)
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = A         Syntax error (as expected)
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = 'A'       Zero records found (as expected)
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = 10A       Syntax error (as expected)
SELECT * from Entity WHERE ID = '10A'     Found Entity 10 (WTF)
```

The final query would appear to ignore the 'A' and evaluate the query as if I had just passed in 10. This is not what I expected.

Is this standard behaviour? I cannot find any doco either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's standard behavior for MySQL.

It's documented under [Type Conversion for Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html).

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

Casting a string to a number results in truncating it at the first non-numeric character, or 0 if the first character is not numeric.

*See also:* [Can I configure MySQL's typecasting to consider 0 != 'foo'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36100/11651)

Note also that the '10A' query (and the 'A' one also) should have thrown a warning.  `SHOW WARNINGS;` after the query to see it.  Your client should have alerted you to the fact that a warning was thrown.  If it didn't, you should complain loudly to the vendor, because that's broken behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When casting a text value to an int, as MySQL does here with your text literals before looking up the id, its behaviour is to use all the numbers up to the first non-number.

Text values that don't have any numbers before the first non number (ie they start with a non number) get cast to 0.

I couldn't find a reference that declared this behaviour as a contract, but here's an [SQLFiddle that shows it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/77787).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: Is it only MySQL that does this? Or should all RDBMS do this?

Comment: @dave afaik it is only MySQL. Other dbs explode with bad input if non digits are encountered.

Comment: @tim couldn't find one, but created sqlfiddle demo. It feels like an impl choice, but one that may not be relied upon in future releases (like so many MySQL quirks)